# Using PDO to avoid SQL injections - newbie

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-injection

I'm trying to use PDO to avoid sql injections and have been looking and searching around for examples and this is what I've come up with, but there are some kind of error somewhere. The database is not getting updated and I get and sql error, but it wont print the details.

```
elseif (isset($_POST["bilnr"])) {

        $name = $_POST['name']; $mobil = $_POST['mobil']; $bilnr = $_POST['bilnr']; $regnr = $_POST['regnr']; $userid = $_COOKIE[userid]; $username = $_COOKIE[user]; 

        $sql=$oDB->Prepare("UPDATE members SET name=:name, mobil=:mobil, bilnr=:bilnr, regnr=:regnr WHERE id=:userid AND username=:username");
        $sql->execute(array(':userid' => $userid);

    if (!$sql) {
        echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
        print_r($oDB->errorInfo());
    }   

    echo "<p class=\"red\">Informasjonen er oppdatert!</p>";
    mysqli_close($con); }
```

If or when I remove the mysqli_close string something crashes and the page just turns blank with no errors. Also with the code above the updates being made in the form dont get into the database.

and the PDO connection in a separate file which is being included

```
$oDB=new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
```

Here is the updated code

```
elseif (isset($_POST["bilnr"])) {

        $name = $_POST['name']; $mobil = $_POST['mobil']; $bilnr = $_POST['bilnr']; $regnr = $_POST['regnr']; $userid = $_COOKIE[userid]; $username = $_COOKIE[user]; 

        $sql=$oDB->Prepare("UPDATE members SET name=:name, mobil=:mobil, bilnr=:bilnr, regnr=:regnr WHERE id=:userid AND username=:username");
        $sql->execute(array(':userid' => $userid,
                    ':name' => $name,
                    ':mobile' => $mobile,
                    ':bilnr' => $billnr,
                    ':regnr' => $regnr,
                    ':username' => $username));

        if (!$sql) {
            echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
            print_r($oDB->errorInfo());
        }       

    echo "<p class=\"red\">Update Done!</p>";
    mysqli_close($con); }
```

The next problem is to get the values into the database, as it is now I don't receive any errors so I'm not sure whats wrong.

**UPDATE**

It works, was just some typo's in the array variables :)

Comment: You can't use `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_error` in a PDO program.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing up mysqli and pdo - you can't use PDO object in mysqli_* functions.

Comment: duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858

Comment: hehe yeah I used the mysql stuff first, then decided to convert to a PDO solution cause I was made aware of the fact that my script was wide open for sql injections :)

Comment: why you are constantly keeping mysqli functions in your code? Can't you use search feature in your editor, eliminate them ALL, then run your code, see if it works and only then post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can't mix `mysqli` and `PDO`. Second, the problem with your query is that you have 6 placeholders, but you're only filling in one of them when you call `execute()`. It should be:

```
$sql->execute(array(':userid' => $userid,
                    ':name' => $name,
                    ':mobile' => $mobile,
                    ':bilnr' => $billnr,
                    ':regnr' => $regnr,
                    ':username' => $username));
```

Comment: Updated the code now, but I still don't get the new form values into the db

Comment: What happened to the incorrect code in the question?

Comment: If you want to show updated code, add it as an **UPDATE** at the end of the question, don't remove the error from the original code. It makes my answer look like nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument for `mysqli_query` must be a string (representation of an SQL query) but you are passing it a PDO prepared query.

Don't mix and match multiple database libraries.

Use `PDO` **or** `mysqli_`.

Comment: Im supposed to use PDO now :)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need mysqli_* functions anymore, scrap 'em (only when you're using PDO) :) When you're using PDO, mysql_* and mysqli_* don't work when combining them. I recommend you to use PDO and not mysql functions anymore. PDO is now well established and is the preferred way.

```
$sql = " 
    INSERT INTO table (name) 
    VALUES (:name) 
    "; 

//Here you prepare the SQL (you already did that correctly).
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 

//You can choose to use bindParam, bindValue or include it in the array (as you do it).
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR); 

$name = 'John'; 
$stmt->execute();
```

This is an **example** how to insert something into a MySQL database with PDO.

Comment: Could anybody explain the downvote? Would love to hear feedback

Comment: This answer is of very poor quality and hardly could be salvaged. strictly speaking, there is nothing wrong with mysqli_* functions and the OP may scrap PDO functions in favor of them as well. Example you posted is too generalized  and helps nothing with the OP

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Feedback taken. I might have answered a bit too quickly indeed. Sorry, won't happen again :) Did an edit too.